How to get document files (.pdf,.doc) from external storage without (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission for Android 11 or above devices
My app got rejected due to All files access permission. I have used (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission and mediastore api to retrieve list of document and download file for Android 11+ devices. thats why my app rejected, what is the solution for this, as I want to show all the files in recyclerview, read and write file from external storage on Android 11+ devices..
any help....
I have used media store API and (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission for reading and writing files from external storage on android 11+ devices. and explained to google play console why i used this permission. but then rejected..

Based on this, Google Play has started limiting which applications can use the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission since May 2021. They have given a list of allowed applications:

File managers
Backup and restore apps
Anti-virus apps
Document management apps
On-device file search
Disk and file encryption
Device-to-device data migration

Since you have not included this information in your question, if you want to get your application approved, your application needs to fall into one of these categories.
